# How many possibilites of a photo from $25$ people?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> A company has $25$ employees.
>
> a) A picture has to be taken of all of the employees for the new
>   company website. How many possibilites are there to order the
>   employees in a row.
>
> b) 7 employees will be picked for a representative group photo. How
>   many possibilites are there of the photo, if the rest of the employees
>   return back to the row.

**a)** I think the answer is $25!$ resulting in a huge number.

**b)** Since we know the order here matters, I used the permuation formula $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=\frac{25!}{(25-7)!}=\frac{25!}{18!}=2422728000$

**Are these valid solutions?**

Answer (score 0):

b) is a bit unclear in my opinion: in case we just want 7 out of 25, it is $\binom{25}{7}$. But if the order matters, we need to multiply the selection by $7!$, as you did.